# How to do more with an expect script than just a log in

Tags: bash, scripts, beagleboard, expect

I have an expect script that logs into my Beaglebone:

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect -f
    spawn ssh debian@192.168.7.2
    expect "debian@192.168.7.2's password:"
    send "temppwd\r"
    interact &&
    mkdir emma &&
    cd emma
```

This works and it logs into the debian account. However, it stops after `interact` the other two commands are not being executed. What do I have to do to do that ?

**EDIT**

ok so thanks andy256 I figured that `interact` is wrong here, however, I get

> invalid command name "mkdir" while executing

How can I combine an expect script with normal shell script?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I guess because the [interact command](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3914)  *gives control of the current process to the user*.

Comment: ah okk, I took it out but then I get a command unknown error for mkdir

Comment: Why not adding your public key to the server to have password less login and run your command with `ssh debian@192.168.7.2 <command>`? Would be lot easier than fiddling with expect

Comment: I tried that with `debian@192.168.7.2 ' "temppwd\r" '` but didn't work

Comment: it stops at the pw question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main thrust of expect programming is `send` and `expect` pairs: you send some text to the spawned process and expect a response. In this case, you send the mkdir command, and expect to see your prompt to know that the command has completed. Prompts are best matched as regular expressions to match the **end** of it. Since prompts are so configurable, you might want to edit the prompt expression: this one matches a literal dollar sign and a space at the end of the string.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh debian@192.168.7.2
expect "debian@192.168.7.2's password:"
send "temppwd\r"
set prompt_re {\$ $}
expect -re $prompt_re
send "mkdir -p emma && cd emma\r"
expect -re $prompt_re
interact
```